# (C++) Having problems writing array contents to a file

Tags: c++, arrays, ofstream

School assignment. Have to basically create a test key for a drivers exam and then validate whether or not the student passed the exam. The correct answers are to be stored in an array and the students answers and full name are to be stored in another array from user input as well as written to a text file.

For a while i thought what i was doing was correct until i went to run the program and noticed that no matter how long the length of the array, it writes a strange I character with an accent above it. It also writes the correct answers of the array to the file which i don't want to do. All i need written to the file is: (full name, student answers (20), full name, student answers (20), etc..)

The first letter of the file is also cut off for some reason. (e.g.. "John Doe" becomes "ohn Doe") What is the reason for this error? without the cin.ignore() statement i am not sure how to get the full name i need into the file.

I have set the array size at the top as a constant allowing me to change it to 4 spaces instead of 20 for quick testing.

Any help is appreciated. Extremely new to programming. Enjoy it so far just have a hard time sometimes.

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void Correct_Answers(const int SIZE, char correctAnswers[]);
void Submitted_Answers(const int SIZE, char submittedAnswers[]);
void Get_Name(string &fullName);



int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 4;
    char correctAnswers[SIZE];
    char submittedAnswers[SIZE];
    string fileName;
    string fullName;
    char go = 'Y';
    ofstream outputObj;

    Correct_Answers(SIZE, correctAnswers);

    cout << "\nEnter the file name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, fileName);
    outputObj.open(fileName);


    while (go == 'Y' || go == 'y')
    {
        Get_Name(fullName);
        outputObj << fullName << endl;

        Submitted_Answers(SIZE, submittedAnswers);
        outputObj << submittedAnswers << endl;

        cout << "\nTo process another user enter Y. To quit enter N: ";
        cin >> go;
    }


    cout << "\n\n\n";
    system("Pause");
    return(0);
}

void Correct_Answers(const int SIZE, char correctAnswers[])
{
    int questionCounter = 0;

    cout << "\nEnter the correct answers for the drivers exam.\n";

    for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++)
    {
        cout << "\tQuestion #" << ++questionCounter << ": ";
        cin >> correctAnswers[x];
        while (correctAnswers[x] != 'A' && correctAnswers[x] != 'a' && correctAnswers[x] != 'B' && correctAnswers[x] != 'b' && correctAnswers[x] != 'C' && correctAnswers[x] != 'c' && correctAnswers[x] != 'D' && correctAnswers[x] != 'd' )
        {
            cout << "\tInvalid entry. Re-enter answer: ";
            cin >> correctAnswers[x];
        }
    }
}

void Submitted_Answers(const int SIZE, char submittedAnswers[])
{
    int questionCounter = 0;

    cout << "\nWelcome to the written portion of the drivers exam!";
    cout << "\nDo your best to answer the questions to the best of your knowledge.";
    cout << "\n15 out of 20 are needed to pass the exam. Best of luck!\n\n";

    for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++)
    {
        cout << "\tQuestion #" << ++questionCounter << ": ";
        cin >> submittedAnswers[x];
        while (submittedAnswers[x] != 'A' && submittedAnswers[x] != 'a' && submittedAnswers[x] != 'B' && submittedAnswers[x] != 'b' && submittedAnswers[x] != 'C' && submittedAnswers[x] != 'c' && submittedAnswers[x] != 'D' && submittedAnswers[x] != 'd')
        {
            cout << "\tInvalid. Re-enter answer: ";
            cin >> submittedAnswers[x];
        }

    }

}

void Get_Name(string &fullName)
{
    cout << "\nEnter the users name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, fullName);
}
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: I have not. I will try that i'm honestly just not sure how to use a debugger but i guess there is only one way to learn. ive just been using compiler error messages to fix most things.

Comment: Compiler errors are issued only when the code you wrote can't be converted to an executable. Not all programs that compile - work correctly, or even in a defined way. You use a debugger, to step through it, line by line, to check if it works correctly.

Comment: Yeah i knew that every program that compiles does not necessarily mean it runs correctly. I've just never used a debugger to step through line by line. Even just now when i tried it didn't seem to tell me anything at all. it opened the console and ran the program and then closed. I will look up how to use it though. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: If you are allergic to debuggers, you can always place "print" statements, that print variable names and their contents.  This is an ancient technique and used when a debugger is not feasible (such as release mode issues).

Comment: Reduce your comparisons, see `toupper` and `tolower`, example: `(toupper(go) == 'Y')`.

Comment: I recommend using `ignore` *after* taking the input you want to ignore, not before taking the next input. Ignoring before taking input sets you up for fun failure cases where you accidentally delete the first letter because there was nothing you wanted to ignore.

Comment: That makes sense, and i do believe i tried that. the problem though was that the loop takes a cin statement for the char's to fill the array. so when i comes back around it need that cin.ignore() statement in order to skip that last char entry. I ended up re writing almost the entire program with a ton of small functions and reference variables. so far its working alot better

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting junk when you write to the file is that when you use >> operator on the file, the ofstream object, you're actually passing it a pointer, and it just keeps reading characters until it finds an end of line or whitespace. For example:

```
int main()
{
    char submittedAnswers[4] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
    char * memptr = submittedAnswers; // Points to "abcdÌÌÌÌ¤ònÉÈø+="
    ofstream outputObj ("d:/filetest.txt");

    outputObj << submittedAnswers << endl;
}
```

Which is why it prints out junk to the file.

The reason why you're losing the first letter of "John Doe" is because you do:

```
cin.ignore(); // This discards the first character.
getline(cin, fullName);
```

So why do you do cin.ignore()? Because you think you have to add cin.ignore() before reading a line for it to work:

```
cout << "\nEnter the file name: ";
cin.ignore(); // You've added this because otherwise getline(cin, fileName)
              // ends up empty
getline(cin, fileName);
outputObj.open(fileName);
```

Why does getline() return an empty string if you leave out cin.ignore()? Because there is still a '\n' newline character in the cin buffer when you call it.

When you take the answers you do:

```
cin >> correctAnswers[x];
```

In a loop. Whenever that line executes it by default skips white spaces and new lines. When you enter an answer you type something and then press enter. When you press enter it adds a '\n' to the buffer. So the command line input is inserted into correctAnswers[], but on the last cin >> you end up with a '\n' character at the end of it, and that's why you had to call cin.ignore before calling getline(), to skip this '\n' character in the buffer.